# how to remove the extension .aspx of first login page on my web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

hi coder i have an application whos default page is login page when every i run my web application `localhost:49194/InventoryTool/Login.aspx` page will appear.

Now what i want is to change that `localhost:49194/InventoryTool/Login.aspx` page to `localhost:49194/InventoryTool/Login` i made some changes in Application_BeginRequest to make that change but its doesn't work

I make changes in global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RoutingData(RouteTable.Routes);
}
private void RoutingData(RouteCollection routeCollection)
{
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("", "Login/", "~/Login.aspx");
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("", "Details/", "~/Details.aspx");
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("", "Reports/", "~/Report.aspx");
    routeCollection.MapPageRoute("", "Error/", "~/Error.aspx");
}
```

by doing this when i go to Login.aspx page it wont change but when i go to details.aspx page it show me Details only

Now can you suggest any thing to me?

Can you give me some ideas how to remove .aspx extension from my login page or can you give me some sample code for that?

Comment: The suggested dupe is outdated, does not use the (Fx 4) routing possibilities.

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks for your comment sir can you suggest what should i do then

Comment: Reopening isn't likely here. You can ask again but be specific, like : "Including Login page in ASP4 routing"

Comment: @HenkHolterman so why not post updated answer in there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement routing or url rewriting to achieve an effect like this.

Comment: guys dont fight i know i have to use url rewriting but the thing is that it won't work on application default  page but if u guys know it also work on default then i am thankful to you thats my question my frnds

Comment: @amitesh, why do you think it wouldn't work on a default page?

Comment: because i try doing it but it didnt work i make many change with my code using url rewriting but nothing work for me thats why i ask question here mate

Comment: i made an edit to my question have a look at it and reply @walther and Shawn